# How to send multiple records in json format

Tags: json, yii

I am creating project in Yii framework. In controller i have function as-

```
public function actiongetCuriosityQuestionAnswer()
{
    $model=new Curiosityquestion;
    $json='{"questionId":1}';
    $obj=json_decode($json);

    $model->questionId=$obj->questionId;
    $record=Curiosityquestion::model()->findByPk($model->questionId);
    echo "The Question=".$record->question."</br>"."Its answer is-".$record->answer;
    echo CJSON::encode($record->answer,$record->question);
}
```

I want to send question and answer in json format. But "`CJSON::encode($record->answer,$record->question);`" is sending only answer in json format. i.e. `CJSON::_encode` is accepting only one parameter. So how to send both question and option in json format together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your whole object to CJSON::encode, e.g.:

```
echo CJSON::encode($record);
```

If you want specific elements, pass as an an array, e.g.:

```
echo CJSON::encode(array('answer'=>$record->answer, 'question'=>$record->question));
```

In your javascript, you can access the elements as javascript objects, e.g. `data['answer']` or something similar